# TypeORM bidirectional composite primary key relations

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, typeorm, bidirectional-relation

One `User` can have multiple `Profiles`. In the `User` I only want to store the `profileId`. In the `Profile` I want to store the id of the `User`.

### User

```
@Entity()
export class User {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: string;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  public profileId?: string;

  @OneToOne(
    type => Profile,
    profile => profile.user
  )
  @JoinColumn()
  profile: Profile;
}
```

### Profile

```
@Entity()
export class Profile {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: string;

  @PrimaryColumn()
  userId: string;

  @OneToOne(
    type => User,
    user => user.profile
  )
  user: User;
}
```

In simple words I want to create two foreign keys. From `User.profileId` to the `Profile.id` and from `Profile.userId` to the `User.Id`. Is this the best practise solution for my problem?

Comment: Having bi-directional FKs can be a maintenance nightmare. Without  extenuating circumstances there is no need for 2 tables. Just move the Profile columns into User table (they have the exact same functional dependencies). If you must maintain both tables drop the profile_id FK from users and create a unique constraint on the user_id FK in profile.